# Create new Object by reading other object with recursive values

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a object `obj1` which has mapping information which is present in other as values `vals`. I am able to create flat object structure but recursive is not working so require help on this

```
const obj1 = [
  {
    mapping: "cities",
  },
  {
    mapping: "category",
    children: {
      mapping: "type",
      children: {
        mapping: "otherType",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    mapping: "age",
  },
];
```

```
const vals = [
  {
    mapping: "category",
    values: [{}],
  },
  {
    mapping: "type",
    values: [{}],
  },
  {
    mapping: "otherType",
    values: [{}],
  },
  {
    mapping: "cities",
    values: [{}],
  },
  {
    mapping: "age",
    values: [{}],
  },
];
```

I want expected data in below fromat

```
const exectedData = {
    cities: {
        values: [{}],
    },
    category: {
        values: [{}],
        children: {
            type: {
                values: [{}],
                children: {
                    otherType: {
                        values: [{}],
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    age: {
        values: [{}]
    }
}
```

With below method i am able to create flat data but recursively data is not coming under `children` property

```
  const processItem = (config, vals) => {
    const isDataAvailable = vals.find(
      (item) => item.category === config.category,
    );

    if (isDataAvailable) {
      if (config.children) {
        processItem(config.children, vals);
      }

      const { mapping } = config;
      finalData.push({
        mapping,
        values: isDataAvailable.values,
      });
    }
  };

  config.forEach((config) => processItem(config, values));
```

Comment: So what is holding you back from doing that? "I want" is not a question.

Comment: I am able to create flat object but recursive not working for me so looking for some suggestion on this

Comment: Please provide your code and how you see there is a problem (wrong output? Infinite loop? Error message? ...) See also [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: I see you have received some good answers to some of your past questions, yet no answer was marked as accepted.

Comment: Have added my implementation what i tried now

Comment: @PuneetBhandari If an answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted. It acknowledges the efforts of the answerer. People don't get paid for it.

Comment: I look at your implementation, but wonder why you create a `mapping` property when there is no such property in your desired output? Also, your desired output has `children` properties, but nowhere in your code do you create such a property. Have you attempted to create the actual properties you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform your values to an object for faster update value finding and make a simple recursion:

```js
const obj = [
  {
    mapping: "cities",
  },
  {
    mapping: "category",
    children: {
      mapping: "type",
      children: {
        mapping: "otherType",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    mapping: "age",
  },
];

const vals = [
  {
    mapping: "category",
    values: [{}],
  },
  {
    mapping: "type",
    values: [{}],
  },
  {
    mapping: "otherType",
    values: [{}],
  },
  {
    mapping: "cities",
    values: [{}],
  },
  {
    mapping: "age",
    values: [{}],
  },
];

const map = vals.reduce((r, {mapping, ...item}) => (r[mapping] = item, r), {});

const update = obj => {
  if(Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.forEach(update);
  if(typeof obj !== 'object') return;
  Object.values(obj).forEach(update);
  Object.assign(obj, map[obj.mapping]);
};

update(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const arr = [
  {
    mapping: "cities",
  },
  {
    mapping: "category",
    children: {
      mapping: "type",
      children: {
        mapping: "otherType",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    mapping: "age",
  },
];

const rec = ({ mapping, children }) =>
  children
    ? {
        [mapping]: {
          values: [{}],
          children: { ...rec(children) },
        },
      }
    : {
        [mapping]: {
          values: [{}],
        },
      };

const tmp = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.mapping) acc = { ...acc, ...rec(item) };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(tmp);
```